# Combine the Output of 3 Transformation in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I'm executing 3 transformations in parallel. the o/p of three transformation contains same column names.
I've added output of all transformation to common dummy step in job and also added WaitForSql step to wait until all 3 transformations have completed execution, and also added unique step in next transformation to remove duplicate records.

All works proper till WaitForSQL, but when next transformation gets rows from result and performs Unique step I get duplicate records also when I perform Unique step.

Has anyone solution for this issue, plz reply.....

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your resulting stream after the dummy step before removing the duplicate rows. The sort will also make sure that all 3 streams are completed before sorting.

I didn't know you could use the dummy step to combine stream results. I always used the `append streams`-step for that.

Comment: I've also sorted rows usong Sort Step before performing Unique step.

Comment: I'm executing a job from that 3 transformations are executing in parallel and now i want to combine and merge the output of 3 transformations

Comment: Afaik you can't combine outputs of different transformations. You would have to execute everything in one transformation. Or you could store all results in a temp table and read/sort that in a fourth transformation.

Comment: The difference between append-streams and a dummy is that in the Dummy rows will be output in the order they arrive, whereas the append-streams allows us to set a head and a tail stream. It depends on requirements, but usually the dummy is a faster way of achieving the result.

Answer (score 0):

Several points:

1. You cannot simply combine the outputs of multiple transformations at the job level. You wil need another transformation to read the data using the Get rows from result; jobs don't know about data streams, they only know about tasks (job entries) and exit status.
2. Be careful with "Launch next entries in parallel" at the job level. Lets say you have 2 transformations, trans1 and trans2, launched in parallel, followed by a dummy step. The dummy will be called TWICE, once after trans1 finishes and another when trans2 finishes. A job hop is not a data stream, it's a workflow. If you want to run transformations in parallel and later go back to a single workflow you need a subjob that calls the transformations and doens't have a Success job entry. That way, the subjob only finishes after the 2nd transformation finishes and only then it goes to the dummy step in the parent.
3. Why do you need those transformations running inside a job? If they have the same column structure, why don't you call them as sub transformations inside a transformation, and not a job? Steps in a transformation are always launched in parallel, so if you're parallelizing things for performance, a transformation is the way to do it, not a job. A job is meant to run multiple tasks in sequential order, one after the other, with workflow control depending on the result of the previous step.

Comment: Thanks, for answer, Now I'm using the transformation executor to call transformation in parallel inside from parent transformation and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Output from three of them into a single file, then you could run the same 3 instances in a single transformation with the append to target option ticked in your output step

Comment: Thanks, for ur reply and now i'm executing 3 transformation instances parallel from my parent transformation